# Какое окончание в слове?

Tags: падежи

поездка на конференцию может помочь в освещении проблем крымских татар, в частности, нарушении их прав на территории.  Меня интересует слово нарушенИИ, или как?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь *общее* понятие обозначено как "проблемы", поэтому "*в частности*" должно относится к одной из "проблем". Значит, изменением окончания в *другом* слове не обойтись и нужно добавить слово "проблема" в том же (родительном) падеже, уже с ним согласовав по падежу слово "нарушение (-ия)":

> ... в освещении *проблем* крымских татар, в частности *проблемы*
>   нарушения их прав...

Comment: Не проблема тут общая, а "освещение". Если бы "проблема", было бы слишком просто.

Comment: Общее понятие, на частности которого здесь ссылаются, - "проблем**ы**". "Освещение" обобщается иначе, напр. так: "_Поездка на конференцию может помочь в освещении, в частности, проблем..._ [= в освещении не только проблем, а и вопросов, планов и т. п.]". Можно и на "помочь" перекинуть эту "общность": _помочь, в частности, в освещении проблем_ [= не только в освещении проблем, а и в обретении известности "поезжающими", во внедрении агентов для проведения диверсий и т. д.].

Comment: не кажется, вы настолько увлеклись совершенствованием фразы, что потеряли мысль автора. Да она грамматически неверно выражена, но почему общие проблемы-то, когда речь идет об освещении?! Нет "проблемы нарушения", есть **нарушение - одна из проблем**.

Comment: Не "общие (для кого-то) проблемы", а общее понятие: "_проблемы_" (мн. число, имен. падеж), в частности проблема, состоящая в том, что "права нарушаются" (_проблема нарушения прав_), и раз уж автор использует  "в частности" сразу после слова "проблемы", то этим он выделяет одну из потенциально освещаемых проблем, а не новую "освещаемую" сущность.

Comment: Кстати, в варианте с обязательным повторением "освещения" (он тоже возможен, если примириться с выражением "освещение нарушений") общее, из которого выбирается частность, не "в освещении", а "в освещении проблем".

Answer (score 0):

Это грамматическая ошибка. Хотя бы потому, что предложный падеж без предлога в современном русском невозможен. Ну и логика фразы получается странная. "Помочь в нарушении"?!

Но фраза вообще очень неудачная, непонятно как править.
По идее должно бы быть

> "Поездка на конференцию может помочь в освещении проблем крымских
>   татар, в частности, [в освещении] нарушений их прав..."

Но без повтора слов "в освещении" это "нарушений" не стыкуется с нужным словом (освещении).

*Дистанцируюсь от политики.*

Answer (score 0):

Можно предложить такой вариант: Поездка на конференцию может помочь в освещении проблем крымских татар, **в частности вопроса о нарушении** их прав на оккупированной территории.